# What "religions" did previous Buddhas practice?

Tags: the-buddha, comparative-religion

I recently found a book called "A Buddhist Bible".

In it, Buddha refers to that there have been many Buddhas before him.
If Buddha was the one to put the foundations of Buddhism, what "religions" did the previous Buddhas practice?

Does this question even make any sense?

Comment: Hi Andrey and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource section](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to tradition, as in the [Nagara Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.065.than.html), Buddhas all discover the path to enlightenment and teach that same path to their followers:

> "It is just as if a man, traveling along a wilderness track, were to
>   see an ancient path, an ancient road, traveled by people of former
>   times. He would follow it. Following it, he would see an ancient city,
>   an ancient capital inhabited by people of former times, complete with
>   parks, groves, & ponds, walled, delightful. He would go to address the
>   king or the king's minister, saying, 'Sire, you should know that while
>   traveling along a wilderness track I saw an ancient path... I followed
>   it... I saw an ancient city, an ancient capital... complete with
>   parks, groves, & ponds, walled, delightful. Sire, rebuild that city!'
>   The king or king's minister would rebuild the city, so that at a later
>   date the city would become powerful, rich, & well-populated, fully
>   grown & prosperous.
>
> "In the same way I saw an ancient path, an ancient road, traveled by
>   the Rightly Self-awakened Ones of former times. And what is that
>   ancient path, that ancient road, traveled by the Rightly Self-awakened
>   Ones of former times? Just this noble eightfold path: right view,
>   right aspiration, right speech, right action, right livelihood, right
>   effort, right mindfulness, right concentration. That is the ancient
>   path, the ancient road, traveled by the Rightly Self-awakened Ones of
>   former times. I followed that path. Following it, I came to direct
>   knowledge of aging & death, direct knowledge of the origination of
>   aging & death, direct knowledge of the cessation of aging & death,
>   direct knowledge of the path leading to the cessation of aging &
>   death. I followed that path. Following it, I came to direct knowledge
>   of birth... becoming... clinging... craving... feeling... contact...
>   the six sense media... name-&-form... consciousness, direct knowledge
>   of the origination of consciousness, direct knowledge of the cessation
>   of consciousness, direct knowledge of the path leading to the
>   cessation of consciousness. I followed that path.
>
> "Following it, I came to direct knowledge of fabrications, direct
>   knowledge of the origination of fabrications, direct knowledge of the
>   cessation of fabrications, direct knowledge of the path leading to the
>   cessation of fabrications. Knowing that directly, I have revealed it
>   to monks, nuns, male lay followers & female lay followers, so that
>   this holy life has become powerful, rich, detailed, well-populated,
>   wide-spread, proclaimed among celestial & human beings."

So, all Buddhas essentially practice and preach the same religion.

Answer (score 2):

According to the story which accompanies the [Dhammapada Verses 183, 184 and 185](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=183),

> While residing at the Jetavana monastery, the Buddha uttered Verses
>   (183), (184) and (185) of this book, with reference to the question
>   raised by Thera Ananda regarding Fundamental Instructions to bhikkhus
>   by the preceding Buddhas.
>
> On one occasion, Thera Ananda asked the Buddha whether the Fundamental
>   Instructions to bhikkhus given by the preceding Buddhas were the same
>   as those of the Buddha himself. To him the Buddha replied that the
>   instructions given by all the Buddhas are as given in the following
>   verses:
>
> Then the Buddha spoke in verse as follows:
>
> 183. Not to do evil, to cultivate merit, to purify one's mind -
>        this is the Teaching of the Buddhas.
> 184. The best moral practice is patience and forbearance;
>        "Nibbana is Supreme", said the Buddhas. A bhikkhu does not harm
>        others; one who harms others is not a bhikkhu.
> 185. Not to revile, not to do any harm, to practise restraint
>        according to the Fundamental Instructions for the bhikkhus, to be
>        moderate in taking food, to dwell in a secluded place, to devote
>        oneself to higher concentration - this is the Teaching of the Buddhas.

Answer (score 0):

Each Buddha rediscovers the same path and the same truth all over again, on his own.

You can find this narrated in the Pali Canon for Vipassi Buddha ([SN 12.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.4/en/sujato)), Sikhi Buddha ([SN 12.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.5/en/sujato)), Vessabhu Buddha ([SN 12.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.6/en/sujato)), Kakusandha Buddha ([SN 12.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.7/en/sujato)), Konagamana Buddha ([SN 12.8](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.8/en/sujato)), Kassapa Buddha ([SN 12.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.9/en/sujato)) and of course, Gotama Buddha ([SN 12.10](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.10/en/sujato)).

Furthermore, the Buddha foretold the coming of the future Buddha, Metteyya Buddha or Maitreya Buddha in [DN 26](https://suttacentral.net/dn26/en/sujato) - to do the same.

Also below:

> Then, having known with his own awareness the line of thinking in the
> Blessed One's awareness — just as a strong man might extend his flexed
> arm or flex his extended arm — Brahma Sahampati disappeared from the
> Brahma-world and reappeared in front of the Blessed One. Arranging his
> upper robe over one shoulder, he saluted the Blessed One with his
> hands before his heart and said to him: "So it is, Blessed One! So it
> is, One-Well-Gone! **Those who were Arahants, Rightly Self-awakened Ones
> in the past** — they, too, dwelled in dependence on the very Dhamma
> itself, honoring and respecting it. **Those who will be Arahants,
> Rightly Self-awakened Ones in the future** — they, too, will dwell in
> dependence on the very Dhamma itself, honoring and respecting it. And
> let the Blessed One, who is at present the Arahant, the Rightly
> Self-awakened One, dwell in dependence on the very Dhamma itself,
> honoring and respecting it."
> [Garava Sutta (SN 6.2)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn06/sn06.002.than.html)